# getting inaccurate estimates from glm with family = gaussian(link = 'inverse')

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, convergence

I believe this is a statistics problem relating to my misunderstanding GLM's.  But there's a chance it's a programming problem. If that turns out to be the case, I'll move over to Stack Overflow.

I've simulated data in a way that I believe would be perfectly captured by a gaussian GLM with the inverse link.  But when I give the data to `stats::glm`, I'm getting inaccurate estimates (or no convergence).

Here's what I mean:

```
set.seed(27599)

n <- 1e4

x1 <- runif(n = n)
x2 <- runif(n = n)

linpred <- 0.5*x1 + -0.5*x2

mu <- 1/linpred
y <- rnorm(n = n, mean = mu, sd = 1)

d <- data.frame(x1, x2, y)

fitted_glm <- glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2,
                  data = d,
                  family = stats::gaussian(link = 'inverse'),
                  mustart = rep(mean(y), n))
coef(fitted_glm)
>  (Intercept)          x1          x2     
>    19247667   -29105253   -16315984
```

I would expect (hope) that the intercept would be near `0` and the effects would be near `0.5` and `-0.5`.

One thing I tried is applying the inverse directly to `y`, rather than to the linear predictor, as in:

```
mu <- mean_lp
y <- 1/rnorm(n = n, mean = mu, sd = 1)

coef(fitted_glm)   

> (Intercept)            x1            x2 
> -1.902150e+12  2.745787e+12 -3.221891e+08
```

But, as you can see, that also gave nonsensical parameter estimates.  Where have I gone wrong?  I used a similar process to simulate and model a normal-identity and normal-log GLM and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if the range of your linear predictor goes across 0, its reciprocal is going to shoot off toward $\pm\infty$ there; you would expect some difficulties with convergence in that case.

See how you go if you make it `1+0.5*x1-0.5*x2` instead. (With the reciprocal link, normally your means should be all-positive. That's not to say it can't work when it does cross 0 -bbrot is right that it converges when you remove the start values- but it's making things hard for yourself and it may not always behave so well.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a numerical problem due to unfortunate initial values for $\mu$. Remove the `mustart`-option from the `glm`-call and everything works as expected.

Comment: I see that this starting value caused problems in this case.  In general, though, `mean(y)` seems like a reasonable starting value to me.  Would you agree?

Comment: In some cases, `mean(y)` may be a good initial value, but here $y$ has a huge variance (`var(y)` = 590846.6, that's because $y$ shoots off to infinity, as Glen_b mentions). In other words, `mean(y)` is pretty far away from the true value of $\mu$ for most observations. It's much better to simply use $y$ as initial values. Try it out, it works...

Comment: Usually, I think there's no need to manually set the initial values. R is quite clever about that.

Comment: got it -- thanks for your input.  Not sure why I didn't think to use `y`!

Comment: @rcorty Setting `mustart=y` is what `glm` does by default, so (as bbrot says) there was never a need for you to set `mustart` yourself.